# What magazine / journal / paper would you subscribe?

Tags: learning

I'm looking for a magazine for IT PMs. I wonder if you subscribe to any of such magazine? If so, what are your recommendations?

I'd prefer a paper version rather that a digital version.

The idea behind this question is: where do you learn from? There are books, experience, trainings / meetings with other PMs. I wonder if you learn from magazines, and if so, what magazines.

Comment: Hi, welcome to PMSE, the site for expert and enthusiast project managers. We generally discourage questions that simply poll the community for answers that aren't necessarily correct. However, if you can edit your question to add more detail about the specific problem you're hoping this magazine/journal, or paper could solve, then I think it would be a great question.

Comment: I would appreciate the address of a IT project management site online.

Answer (score 3):

I realize this isn't a IT PM mag but... Harvard Business Review would be my vote. Good take on the management side of things, case studies, etc. to help develop your soft skills.

Comment: This is also one of my favorite overall sites to visit.

Answer (score 3):

As for periodicals that have a paper version and some emphasis on management/project management within an IT context (some with lighter coverage than others), I read the following:

- [CIO](http://www.cio.com/)
- [Inc.](http://www.inc.com/)
- [Fast Company](http://www.fastcompany.com/)
- [Harvard Business Review](http://hbr.org/magazine)

I do, however, read all of those online.

Other online periodicals that I read regularly come from the [PMI](http://www.pmi.org) itself; these are all worth the price of membership (to me):

- [PM Network](http://www.pmi.org/Knowledge-Center/Publications-PM-Network.aspx)
- [Project Management Journal](http://www.pmi.org/Knowledge-Center/Publications-Project-Management-Journal.aspx)

To continue answering your question "where do you learn from?", my answer is that while I *glean* information and accumulate knowledge from always paying attention to what is circulating around me (such as by reading these periodicals), I *learn* the most in conversations with others through local meetings and presentations, [#PMChat on Twitter](http://www.michaelgreer.biz/pmfreebies/?p=812), and the articles/information shared via membership in PMI Communities of Practice.  Specifically:

- [Agile CoP](http://agile.vc.pmi.org/)
- [Information Systems CoP](http://is.vc.pmi.org/)
- [IT & Telecommunications CoP](http://itt.vc.pmi.org/)

I realize several of my answers are specific to PMI membership (which is different than PMI Certification -- you can be a member and have access to all of these benefits but not be certified) but that's my answer *for me*.  I am sure that other organizations have similar benefits.

Answer (score 2):

I have never subscribed to such a magazine but as a result of your question I have become curious if there is any good magazine and I have done small research/look-up for such.

I have use following criteria:

- should be about project management in general
- at least some content focused on IT area
- more popular one than academic one

  - something for reading on evenings at home

Based on above I have found these two interesting:

- [project manager today](http://www.pmtoday.co.uk/)
- [management today](http://www.managementtoday.co.uk/)

Hope this will help you a bit. I will possibly subscribe to one of them so I will hopefully add some real life experience at some time later.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend Inc.com (it has a paper version too).

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer a paper version, perhaps you can qualify for free subscription. Have a look at [reportergene.tradepub.com](http://reportergene.tradepub.com/category/information-technology/1207/). Several IT magazine subscriptions are offered for free.

Answer (score 1):

[PM Network](http://www.pmi.org/Knowledge-Center/Publications-PM-Network.aspx) has many articles relevant to IT PM.

Also, the PM Journal (put out by Wiley and PMI on a quarterly basis) has tons of good material -though it is more on the academic side.

Answer (score 1):

[Baseline](http://www.baselinemag.com/) and [CIO](http://www.cio.com/) are my first choices for paper magazines. I also agree that Harvard Business Review and Fast Company are great resources.

Answer (score 0):

I've just seen an [Inc](http://www.inc.com/) advertisement. They have different kind of magazines even printed versions, and based on a couple of articles I've seen so far they cover pretty good topics.